# Flutter PlatformViews: Trying to create a platform view of unregistered type

Tags: android, kotlin, flutter

So, I followed this [article](https://60devs.com/how-to-add-native-code-to-flutter-app-using-platform-views-android.html) from 60devs, on how to implement native Webview in flutter using PlatformView. I followed the article exactly but I get this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, Trying to create a platform view of unregistered type: webview, null)
```

> - My minimum SDK version is greater than 20 (21 currently).
> - I have **internet permission** in my `AndroidManifest.xml` file.
> - I have tried `flutter clean`.

But nothing works.

flutter run error:

```
E/flutter ( 8794): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, Trying to create a platform view of unregistered type: webview, null)
E/flutter ( 8794): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope 
package:flutter/…/services/message_codecs.dart:564
E/flutter ( 8794): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod 
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:316
E/flutter ( 8794): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8794): #2      AndroidViewController._create 
package:flutter/…/services/platform_views.dart:639
E/flutter ( 8794): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8794): #3      AndroidViewController.setSize 
package:flutter/…/services/platform_views.dart:556
E/flutter ( 8794): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8794): #4      RenderAndroidView._sizePlatformView 
package:flutter/…/rendering/platform_view.dart:189
E/flutter ( 8794): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8794): #5      RenderAndroidView.performResize 
package:flutter/…/rendering/platform_view.dart:170
E/flutter ( 8794): #6      RenderObject.layout 
package:flutter/…/rendering/object.dart:1604
E/flutter ( 8794): #7      _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout 
package:flutter/…/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105
E/flutter ( 8794): #8      RenderObject.layout 
package:flutter/…/rendering/object.dart:1619
E/flutter ( 8794): #9      _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout 
package:flutter/…/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105
E/flutter ( 8794): #10     RenderObject.layout 
package:flutter/…/rendering/object.dart:1619
E/flutter ( 8794): #11     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout 
package:flutter/…/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105
E/flutter ( 8794): #12     RenderObject.layout 
package:flutter/…/rendering/object.dart:1619
E/flutter ( 8794): #13     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout 
package:flutter/…/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105
E/flutter ( 8794): #14     RenderObject.layout 
package:flutter/…/rendering/object.dart:1619
E/flutter ( 8794): #15     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout 
package:flutter/…/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105
E/flutter ( 8794): #16     RenderObject.layout 
package:flutter/…/rendering/object.dart:1619
E/flutter ( 8794): #17     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout 
package:flutter/…/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105
E/flutter ( 8794): #18     RenderObject.layout 
package:flutter/…/rendering/object.dart:1619
E/flutter ( 8794): #19     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout 
package:flutter/…/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105
E/flutter ( 8794): #20     RenderObject.layout 
package:flutter/…/rendering/object.dart:1619
E/flutter ( 8794): #21     RenderOffstage.performLayout 
package:flutter/…/rendering/proxy_box.dart:3074
```

Can you **please** look at the code in this [article](https://60devs.com/how-to-add-native-code-to-flutter-app-using-platform-views-android.html), it's short and simple. And tell me what went wrong?

Comment: Even i have implemented that tutorial. But, it is not properly implemented and tested.I think the writer has copied the article from a medium post and copy pasted it without even understanding the concept. I have tried platform view many times. But, didn't got any luck. If you understand this concept any day then please comment here to explain. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please print the info of flutter doctor -v, maybe 1.5.4hotfix can't work with platform view.